# Jquery - Toggle Class On Multiple Buttons

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

I currently am running with a small JQuery function that toggles a new class if a button has been clicked.

```
    $(".button1").click(function () {

        $(this).toggleClass("button2");

    });
```

This works fine, however, my issue is that I have 5 buttons in a row and I only want one to have the new class at a time. At the moment if i click any of the other buttons they also get the new class applied. I want it, if someone clicks another button, to remove the button2 class from the original button and apply it only to the newley clicked button.

Any thoughts on achieving this?

Comment: So, you want this will apply only the one `button` which you `clicked` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".button1").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find(".button2").removeClass("button2");
    $(this).addClass("button2");
});
```

Comment: This will only work if these buttons have a common parent container, but is an otherwise good solution.

Comment: @MikeBrant You are right. Since there are no HTML in the question I had to assume something. You can always replace `$(this).parent()` with `$("#buttons_container_id")` or even `$(body)`. Generic question => generic answer :-)

Comment: Thats exactly what I was after. There is a parent class, I should have included the html.

Answer (score 1):

Use [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not) for that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $(".button1").click(function () {    

        $('.button2').not(this).removeClass('button2');
        $(this).toggleClass("button2");    
    });    
});
```

Read http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-not-this

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/NXBqU/1/

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
$('.button1').click(function () {
    $('.button2').removeClass('button2');
    $(this).addClass('button2');
});
```